# Unable to run php file in background

Tags: php, mysql, command-line-interface

I want to run a php file in background which has some mysql commands, I am unable to do so.
Is it that php file based on cakephp framework doesnot run in background?
To run a php file n background do i need to write it basic php format
I am a beginner.
I have tried commands like:

```
php filename.php
php filename.php &
php -a
exec( '/usr/bin/php -f /my/path/to/filename.php > /dev/null &' );
```

followed this tutorial "http://www.xphp.info/background-processing-with-php/"

please tell me.

the code is:

```
<?php


include_once "a_file.php";


class Calci{


    var $ft = 350;
    var $fl = 130;
    var $lt = 60;    
    var $fbCount = 0;
    var $liCount = 0;
    var $twCount = 0;
    var $nodeId = 0;

    function index() {   
        App::import('model', 'User');
        $user_model = new User();

        $entry = $user_model->find("all", array("conditions" => array("not" => array("User.id" => null))));
        foreach($entry as $e) {
            $user_id = $e["User"]["id"];
            $tr=$this->getTrUser($user_id);
            $this->$e["User"]["id"]=$user_id;
            $this->$e["User"]["true_reach"]=$tr;
            $this->$e["User"]->save();
        }    
    }
    function getTrUser($id) {
// some calculation

}

}    

?>
```

Comment: It may or may not be cakephp dependent. Depends what is the content in your `filename.php`

Comment: I am using that file to update a row in table it fetches all the rows from the tables and updates them.

Comment: which of the 3 commands do you need to run in background?

Comment: It would make more sense to post the code of the file here rather than abstractly explaining what's happening inside the file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process

Comment: have you checked logs ?

Comment: ya nothing much there

Comment: okay, tried using `php-cli`, as suggested in my answer ?

Comment: yes brother no result

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `php-cli`, to execute php script using `exec`

```
exec('php-cli /var/www/gohachi-git/app/services/hachicalci.php > /dev/null &');
```

Comment: in the php interpreter

Comment: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `'php-cli /var/www/gohachi-git/app/services/hachicalci.php > /dev/null &''

Answer (score 0):

If your using SSH / Terminal use:

```
nohup php /my/path/to/filename.php &
```

Comment: it didnt work it gave the contents of the file as output to nohup.out

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to use the Mysql Event Scheduler and Stored Procedures for run this queries.